vectorize.upstream_error - failed to parse upsert vectors request in ndjson format: line Some(0) was not expected format
I am trying to upsert a vector in my cloudflare vectorize index
For now I am testing from my terminal using cURL
Call I am making is this:
curl -v --request POST --url https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/my_account_id/vectorize/v2/indexes/c1-vectorize/upsert   --header 'Authorization: Bearer redacted'   --header 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson'   --data @vector-data-clean-utf8.ndjson

Here is what the vector-data-clean-utf8.ndjson file looks like:
{"id":"s4444","values":[175.1, 167.1, 129.9],"metadata":{"url":"/products/sku/918318313"}}
{"id":"5555","values":[158.8, 116.7, 311.4],"metadata":{"url":"/products/sku/183183183"}}
{"id":"6666","values":[113.2, 67.5, 11.2],"metadata":{"url":"/products/sku/717313811"}}

This is exactly what the example ndjson file on the vectorize page of cloudflare page is.
Yet, no matter what variation I try, I get this error:
"errors": [
    {
      "code": 40023,
      "message": "vectorize.upstream_error - failed to parse upsert vectors request in ndjson format: line Some(0) was not expected format"
    }
  ]

The error does not provide any more details that this, so I am trying to understand how to overcome this.
Any help is appreciated as I could not find much help with this problem.
Regards
Cleaned the file for spaces , trimmed it
Ensured no newline at the end of file or beginning of file
Checked the type of the file, changed it to utf-8 from us-ascii
Tried using a normal JSON file, no luck either

looks like the example in the Cloudflare documentation is incorrect, I created  the index, and couldn't upload the NDJSON file, as well.
After some research I figure out that for upload the NDJSON file, the --data-binary option should be used. This is because NDJSON stands for 'Newline Delimited JSON', and the curl option --data strips newlines from the file.
Based on this, my curl request looks like:
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/my_account_id/vectorize/v2/indexes/c1-vectorize/upsert \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer redacted' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' \
  --data-binary @/tmp/data

Where is my /tmp/data looks like:
{"id": "4444", "values": [0.12, 0.34, 0.56], "metadata": {"url": "/products/sku/918318313" }}
{"id": "4443", "values": [0.12, 0.38, 0.74], "metadata": {"url": "/products/sku/918318314" }}

Please note: this is reduced example, because dimensions must be in range: [32, 1536].
And Cloudflare response was:
{
  "result": {
    "mutationId": "b66e7281-c65e-47b6-87e8-c05a06c422ec"
  },
  "success": true,
  "errors": [],
  "messages": []
}

